# Enable ssh, vnc or something similar during installation of Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, installation, ssh-tunnel, headless

I have a headless Scaleo Home Server 2205 that I'm thinking of installing Ubuntu Server on. Then on top of that I was thinking of using greyhole and CrashPlan to mimic some of the original WHS functionality. But since it's headless I would have to either fiddle with hooking it up to a graphics card using a 1x-16x pcie adapter etc. I have done it before but it's a bit of a hassle since my graphics card need extra power and the Scaleo can't support that and so on.

I was wondering if it would be possible to run an unattended install of Ubuntu Server from a USB stick or even better, have the setup enable ssh or some other form of communications option during the installation so I could manage the installation from another computer. Does any such solution exist?

Comment: http://serverfault.com/questions/463/how-can-i-configure-unattended-installation-of-ubuntu Is likely what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This Ubuntu help article](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/NetworkConsole) describes how to modify the netboot installer to automate things far enough to make SSH available.

Warning: I haven't tested it myself.