# Clone Ubuntu to Another Hardware

Tags: ubuntu, clone, ghost

My organization is planning to move from a Windows Environment to a Ubuntu based Linux environment. We need to mass migrate about 60 pcs to Ubuntu, with a all the custom applications needed.

We find it cumbersome to have to go and add these custom applications after each Ubuntu installation.

I would like to know if there is any system that will clone my pre-configured Ubuntu system into a boot CD, which can be installed in other PCs. Please note these PCs have different hardware configurations, but all of them are 32bit platforms.

Comment: http://tinyurl.com/4yg7oah

Answer (score 0):

It's not ghost, but you should, as someone commented, google for "unattended ubuntu install" or similar.  [This](https://serverfault.com/questions/463/how-can-i-configure-unattended-installation-of-ubuntu) result in particular looks promising.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your answers. I ended using the Clonezilla SE. I set up a Ubuntu system with all the Custom programs and installations. Cloned the system over the network using Clonezilla SE. Then restored it over the network to other new systems. It worked beautifully.

I used [this great blog post](http://geekyprojects.com/cloning/setup-a-clonezilla-server-on-ubuntu/) to setup Clonezilla.